# Customer Service: Case Teams vs Groups

Tags: servicecloud, public-group, case-teams

Scenario: 
there are n **groups** receiving calls in a Call Center: **A**, **B**, **C**, **D**. When a Case is received it is seen by all the members of the group. When one of them takes the case in charge, the other members of his group cannot see the Case anymore.

Scenario in Salesforce:

1. there are the *Queues*: **Aq**, **Bq**, **Cq**, **Dq**.
2. there are the *Public Groups*: **Ag**, **Bg**, **Cg**, **Dg**.
3. the group Ag is on the queue Aq, the group Bg in on the queue Bq, etc etc.
4. When a case is put on a group it is seen by the people of that group.

The problem: 
The coordinator of the groups cannot see "the work done by a group". On the Dashboards he can only see the cases assigned to the different users and the cases assigned to the groups, but not measures grouping users in the same groups.

Possible solution:
using Case Teams? Does it make sense to eliminate the ***Public Groups*** substituting them with ***Case Teams***? Is there something cannot work with the second ones?